# Docker ADD folder with zip files result in Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I want to add a folder which contains zip files to my docker image, it has been working for weeks now but now it is throwing this error:

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
```

I also tried with old zip files and its not working. I am executing this in gitlab-ci with docker:dind image.

```
ADD packages/ /opt/packages/
```

One of these files is nearly 9GB in size. I really don't know what the problem is. I also tried:

```
 chmod -R 777 packages
```

The files are definitely in packages folder. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Have you tried manually checking the contents of the zip file (`tar -tvf file.tar`)?

Comment: Yes as far as I can see it looks good, but in the zip file more than 100k files.

Comment: any other idea? limitation in size? docker build context size?

Comment: Out of disk on the host where the docker daemon is running?

Comment: How long does it take until you see the error? also running `docker -D -l debug build ...` might give some hints

Comment: This is running in gitlab ci, maybe the gitlab runner is out of space, but I don't know how this is configured.  Is there a limitation in disk space for a runner? It is running in kubernetes where each node has 1 TB disk space and was working before with the same zip files/same size. I will try with the debug options.

Comment: The debug does not show more than before, I only get "Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF" The error shows up after around 20 seconds after executing "ADD packages/ /opt/packages/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [8GB size limit](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37581) in the 18.06 release of docker. I'd recommend subscribing to the github issue on this to get notified of updates. It's also a good best practice to avoid creating images with large layers like this. If you have a large data file, consider including it as a volume into the container rather than building it into the image.

Comment: I am using, image: docker:17.12.1-dind so this shouldn't be a problem right? Or can it be that the underlying version of gitlab-ci docker is causing this?

Comment: Does this mean an Image can never be bigger than 8GB ?

Comment: I've seen some suggestions this linked bug is specific to MacOS. However if the parent filesystem ran out of space or your user reached a filesystem quota, that would generate the same result.

Comment: Just an update, I've also seen this on a native Linux install, so it's not exclusive to MacOS.

Comment: there are some possibilities, but I just executed it on a dedicated VM and I got the same error. So its not a problem with disk space or the gitlab runner. maybe the file is corrupt, is there a way to check a file being corrupt? sha256sum but I don't have a source sha. I will verify with just a large file tmrw.

Comment: So I just tested it with installing this version of docker in my VM with "sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu" and it works. So this is really a problem with a specific version of docker. So my question is again, could this be caused by the version of Gitlab-CI docker version. I am not 100% sure how gitlab is build. But I guess the pipelines run on docker itself and if I am using Docker in the pipeline it's some sort of docker in docker and could cause this? I will investigate further...

Comment: @TimSchwalbe try upgrading to 18.09, they fixed it: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37771